# Как я могу удалить компонент React из DOM после клика по button внутри него?

Tags: reactjs

Структура компонента:

```
<div classname="parent">
    <div>something</div>
    <button classname="child"></button>
</div>
```

Компонент вызывается в другом компоненте:

```
<Button />
```

Как при клике на кнопку внутри компонента удалить его из DOM структуры?

Comment: опишите подробнее проблему. трудно понять  что  где  должно находится

Answer (score 0):

Можно сверху дерева объявить стейт isShowButton например

```
const [isShowButton, setIsShowButton] = useState(true);
{isShowButton && <Button onRemoveButton={setIsShowButton(false)} />}
```

И внутри компонента кнопки повесить onClick:

```
<div classname="parent">
    <div>something</div>
    <button classname="child" onClick={() => props.onRemoveButton()}></button>
</div>
```

Если я правильно понял конечно))

Можно еще на button повесить id и по id удалить прям из dom дерева

```
document.getElementById("id").remove();
```